# How to set a device-wide in-app-purchase block?

Tags: google-play-store, in-app-purchase

Similar to the Apple iOS' "[restrictions mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204396)", is there a way to bar in-app purchases device-wide?

Would prefer a solution for unrooted devices, but if the only way is by rooting, so be it.

The Play Store is password protected for every purchase, so the main issue is not preventing the purchase itself, but something like blocking the opening of the Play Store or the forwarding of the screen to the store, something in that line.

Comment: You can set the play store to require the google account password in order to make a purchase. That may or may not work for you, depending on your situation.

Comment: @ak11234 it is already set, but I want something that blocks the app from even forwarding to the play store.